# Anylogic: How can I make an agent on a conveyor pass through certain stations without processing

Tags: anylogic

I am modelling a simple system with one conveyor and four stations placed on it in series. I want the material agents travelling on the conveyor to be conditionally processed by only one of the stations, and NOT be processed by the other three, just pass through them. For simplicity, assume that the condition is a variable randomly set in the material agent.

I tried conditionally setting the processing time to 0 for when the station was not supposed to process the material agent, but this has two drawbacks: 1) It still triggers "on process finished" condition, and 2) I have two worker resources working with the four stations - when they are both working on a station, then a third material agent can't even pass through any of the other two stations, because it needs a free worker resource to "nudge" it forward. So the processing is still taking place in the station for a single instant, instead of not taking place at all.

I suppose I just want to ask if there is a way to conditionally deactivate a station and treat it as a normal conveyor segment.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the station element.  Use 4 *Position on Conveyor* markup elements.  In your convey block, you can send to your position of choice.  This can either be random or with some complex logic.  Have your seizing, delaying, etc be with your logical blocks, not with your space markup.  In the example below, I just dropped a service on, which is a queue, seize, delay, release all in one.
[image]